# Follow up to certificate sharing question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Follow up to the post [Sharing certificates encryped by password between DBs and instances](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/sharing-certificates-encryped-by-password-between-dbs-and-instances)

I created a certificate with a password

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE testcert
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'test123' 
WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate for stored procedures using dynamic SQL',
START_DATE = '2010-01-01',
EXPIRY_DATE = '2100-01-01'
```

I then removed the private key

```
ALTER CERTIFICATE testcert REMOVE PRIVATE KEY
```

Finally, I attempt to backup the certificate

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE testcert TO FILE = 'd:\mssql\testcert.cer' 
WITH PRIVATE KEY ( DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'S3creT!' ,
FILE = 'd:\mssql\testcert.pvk' , 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'test123' );
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 15246, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot dump the private key of
>   certificate 'testcert' because the private key cannot be found.

Which seems normal since I dropped the private key.

1st Question: Using the method explained in the previous post, does this mean that to backup the certificate I would use this statement?

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE testcert TO FILE = 'd:\mssql\testcert.cer'
```

2nd Question: What would you do to then to restore the certificate to another server and database?

Example :

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE testcert2       
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'test123',
FROM FILE = 'd:\mssql\testcert.cer'     
WITH PRIVATE KEY ....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you backup and restore a certificate *for the purpose of moving the certificate* you shouldn't have to include any clause related to the private key. I explained in the linked post the reasoning why the value of private key derives primarily from it's *uniqueness* and any operation that duplicates a private key dillutes its value:

- it can no longer be used as proof of identiy (ie. signature) since multiple copies exists throughout the world and [non-repudiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) is busted
- it can no loger be used as a secure means to achieve privacy (ie. encrypt with corresponding public key) because since multiple copies exists, a copy may had been compromised

Just to drive the point home, a certificate is a ['an electronic document which uses a digital signature to bind a public key with an identity'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) and the correct terminology is *public key certificate*. In other words **a certificate does not have a private key**. I myself am carefull to say 'certificate *and the associated private key*'.

The few operations when is acceptable to backup and restore a certificate *and the associated private key* are [key escrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_escrow)  and backup for recovery purpose (not for *move*).

Now after this long dissertation, the answers:

1. yes, use `BACKUP CERTIFICATE testcert TO FILE = 'd:\mssql\testcert.cer'`
2. Use `CREATE CERTIFICATE testcert2 FROM FILE = 'd:\mssql\testcert.cer'`

Comment: Thank you Remus +1.  If you were going to sign a stored procedure in the database where you restored the certificate, would you then add back a private key to the certificate?

Comment: You cannot 'add back' a private key. The private key and public key form a cryptographic match. Once the private key is dropped one can never use the same 'certificate' (actually the same [key-pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_pair)) to sign again a procedure. This is *exaclty* why I recommend dropping the private key after the procedure is signed: nobody can come later and sign a *different* procedure and use this as a measn to escalate priviledges. When a new procedure needs to be signed, generate a *new* certificate (a ney key pair).

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining. I understand now what you meant when you said that he was doing it all wrong.

Comment: In the linked post question even if he chooses not to drop the private key after signing, there still is absoilutely no reason to *share* the private key between instances. Sharing between DBs *may* be argued for due do proliferation of certificate derived logins in `[master]`, but once you do that you accept a compromise in the strenght of your security story (compromise of the private key in DB1 can lead to low priviledges users in DB1 to gain access to many more DBs and other attack vectors may be exposed).